# Trying to get property 'created_at' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

I want to display created_at from table / model Post.
So I write this code

If I `var_dump`. It works
[image]

I want to echo this

```
{{$user->post->first()->created_at}}
```

But it went wrong [image]

I don't know why it is trying to get property of non object

Comment: Please post the var_dump code.

Comment: its simple because of $user->post->first() is returning empty/null

Comment: 0

Hello ,

because of no any value in your database table field so first of all you can fill the value of created_at then you will get your proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have to call `first()` on your eager loaded relationship. You can just do:

```php
$user->post->created_at
```

or

```php
$user->post()->first()->created_at
```